# Warning: Error in .local: Failed to connect to database: Error: Unknown database 'shinyapps'

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I am connecting to my mysql database with shiny in R. I got the error message as shown in the title. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Can you connect to MYSQL from command line?

Comment: yes I can connect to my database from the command line

Comment: why is the error message saying unknown database shinyapps when I don't have a database named that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be specific when you ask questions, showing your (related!) code, what the problem is, what you tried to fix it, what you got and what you expected instead. In your case, I would suggest you google a bit. If you cannot find the answer you seek doing that, come back here and update your question with what you found out, including the code used.